# EntityFrameworkCore Audit Exclude

Tags: entity-framework

I'm using Z.EntityFramework.Plus to audit my database changes.

To include what entities I want to follow, I'm using the next configuration:

```
AuditManager.DefaultConfiguration.Exclude(x => true); // Exclude ALL
AuditManager.DefaultConfiguration.Include<Customer>();
```

With above code all entities of type Customer are audited.

But now, I want to audit only certain customers. For example, I would like to audit only active customers. So, only customers with property IsActive=true should be audited.

I tried using something like the following:

```
AuditManager.DefaultConfiguration.Exclude(w => w.GetType() == typeof(Customer) && ((Customer)w).IsActive);
```

But the above doesn't work.

Where can I add a condition to exclude all inactive customers from audit tables?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is currently a smart way to try to exclude/include entities, but not supported by the library because of those lines of code: https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Plus/blob/master/src/shared/Z.EF.Plus.Audit.Shared/AuditConfiguration/IsAuditedEntity.cs#L38-L41

However, your case could be supported if you ask for it on the [GitHub Issue Tracker](https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Plus/issues) (Make sure you reference this post)

We cannot support it by default as it makes the check for every entity if we should audit it or not slower, but we can add an option that will enable this.